# Python Numpy. Delete an element (or elements) in a 2D array if said element is located between a pair of specified elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, conditional-statements

I have a 2D NumPy array exclusively filled with 1s and 0s.

```
a = [[0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1]
     [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
     [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
     [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1]
     [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
     [1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1]
     [1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1]
     [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]
```

To get the location of the 0s I used the following code:

```
new_array = np.transpose(np.nonzero(a==0))
```

As expected, I get the following result showing the location of the 0s within the array

```
new_array = [[0 0]
             [0 1]
             [0 2]
             [0 3]
             [0 5]
             [0 6]
             [0 7]
             [3 4]
             [3 5]
             [3 6]
             [3 7]
             [5 3]
             [6 6]
             [6 7]]
```

Now comes my question:
Is there way to get the location of the 0s at the start and end of and horizontal group if said group is larger than 2?

EDIT: If group were to finish at the end of a row and continue on the one below it, it would count as 2 separate groups.

My first thought was to implement a process that would delete 0s if they are located in-between 0s but I was not able to figure out how to do that.

I would like "new_array" output to be:

```
new_array = [[0 0]
             [0 3]
             [0 5]
             [0 7]
             [3 4]
             [3 7]
             [5 3]
             [6 6]
             [6 7]]
```

Thanks beforehand!!

### EDIT 2:

Thanks you all for your very helpful insights, I was able to solve the problem that I had.

To satisfy the curiosity, this data represents musical information. The purpose of the program I'm working on is to create a musical score based on a image (that consist exclusively of horizontal lines).

Once the image conversion to 1s and 0s is done, I needed to extract the following information from it: Onset, Pitch, and Duration. This translates into position in the "x" axis, position on the "y" axis and total length of group.

Since X and Y locations are fairly easy to get, I decided to process them separately from the "Duration" calculation (which was the main problem to solve in this post).

Thanks to your help I was able to solve the Duration problem and create a new array with all necessary information:

```
[[0 0 4]
 [5 0 3]
 [4 3 4]
 [6 6 2]]
```

Note that 1st column represent Onset, 2nd column represents Pitch, and 3rd column represents Duration.

It has also come to my attention the comment that suggested to add an identifier to each event. Eventually I will need to implement that to differentiate between different instruments (and later sending them to individual Midi channels). However, for this first iteration of the program that only aims to create a music score for a single instrument, it is not necessary since all events belong to a single instrument.

I have very little experience with programming, I don't know if this was the most efficient way of achieving my goal. Any suggestions are welcomed.

### Thanks!

Comment: Would really want a 1-dimensional sequence of alternating start and end of runs? Wouldn't a sequence of tuples or a width 2 array make more sense? Also, if a run were to end at the end of a row, and continue on the next row, is that one run, or are they two runs?

Comment: You need to avoid `for`-like iterations in `numpy` because they are slow. Use `np.transpose(np.nonzero(a==0))` instead

Comment: @Grismar Indeed, as shown in the provided example I would want "new_array" to be width 2 showing the start and end of runs and ignoring the 0s in-between if they run has a length larger than 2. 

For the 2nd part of your question, for the purposes of the data, it would count as a two separate runs.

Comment: FWIW: I have a concern about your proposed output. It won't correctly distinguish between single runs and longer runs. Consider `[0 1 0 1]` vs `[0 0 0 1]`. They will both result in `[[0 0] [0 2]]`, in your final representation. Its better to represent as start location and run count. I might represent the first as `[[0 0 1] [0 2 1]]` and the second as `[[0 0 3]]`. Though I probably wouldn't keep it in numpy format; would instead do `[[0 0], 3]` or maybe `[0, 0], 3]`. I mean, at that stage I would write ordinary Python code to manipulate simple objects.

Comment: @I-like-weird-sounds apologies, my question for clarification was poorly phrased - I figured an array of shape `(5, 2, 2)` would make more sense `[[[0 0][0 3]][[0 5][0 7]][[3 4][3 7]][[5 3][5 3]][[6 6][6 7]]]`, especially because in the format you are suggesting, it's unclear if `[5 3][6 6]` is an interval, or that `[5 3]` should be interpreted as a single `0` - you can only tell if you go back to the original data.

Comment: Thanks! see Edit 2 on OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A flaw in the other solution is that it reports **all** sequences
of zeroes, regardless of their length.
Your expected output also contains such groups, composed of 1 or 2
zeroes, but in my opinion it shouldn't.

My solution is free of the above flaw.

An elegant tool to process groups of **adjacent** equal elements is
*itertools.groupby*, so start from:

```
import itertools
```

Then generate your intended result as:

```
res = []
for rowIdx, row in enumerate(a):
    colIdx = 0  # Start column index
    for k, grp in itertools.groupby(row):
        vals = list(grp)        # Values in the group
        lgth = len(vals)        # Length of the group
        colIdx2 = colIdx + lgth - 1  # End column index
        if k == 0 and lgth > 2: # Record this group
            res.append([rowIdx, colIdx])
            res.append([rowIdx, colIdx2])
        colIdx = colIdx2 + 1    # Advance column index
result = np.array(res)
```

The result, for your source data, is:

```
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 3],
       [0, 5],
       [0, 7],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 7]])
```

As you can see, it doesn't include shorter sequences of zeroes
in row 5 and 6.

Comment: Ah, I missed _"if said group is larger than 2"_ in OP. I was guiding by the desired output which contradicts the statement. It would be nice for @I-like-weird-sounds to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution that is easier to follow is:

```
b = np.diff(a, prepend=1)  # prepend a column of 1s and detect
                           # jumps between adjacent columns (left to right)
y, x = np.where(b > 0)  # find positions of the jumps 0->1 (left to right)
# shift positive jumps to the left by 1 position while filling gaps with 0:
b[y, x - 1] = 1
b[y, x] = 0
new_array = list(zip(*np.where(b)))
```

Another one is:

```
new_array = list(zip(*np.where(np.diff(a, n=2, prepend=1, append=1) > 0)))
```

Both solutions are based on the [`np.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) that computes differences between consecutive columns (when `axis=-1` for 2D arrays).

Comment: IMHO, that code needs a line-by-line explanation. With sample data. I'm not seeing how `np.where(b > 0)` does what is needed.

Comment: This is about as good as it'll get to get exactly what OP asks for. However, it also has exactly the problem pointed out in the comments, which is that it would be impossible to reconstruct the original array from the outcome (given the shape of the original array), since it's unclear how the values ought to be paired, as single values only have a single set of coordinates. I feel that makes the solution perfect, yet useless. Deserves credit though, very concise.

Comment: @Grismar Thanks! _"it would be impossible to reconstruct the original array from the outcome"_ - I do not think that inability to reconstruct original array makes this solution (or question) useless. It may be useful solution for the forward problem to the user.

Comment: 'Useless' may be a bit strong, but what I meant to say is it is impossible to understand the outcome unambiguously. For example, does `[3 4]` signify a single `0`, as well as `[3 7]`, or does it signify a run of zeroes from `[3 4]` to `[3 7]` - it's impossible to tell and an input array with either would yield the same result. However, it's what OP asked for, so perhaps they have a use for it in spite of the ambiguity.

Comment: @Grismar I understand (and agree) with your reasoning but all I was saying was that OP _may have_ valid (, for their specific problem,) reasons for this specific way of doing things.

Comment: Thanks! see Edit 2 on OP.